# failing to install sagemath on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sagemath

i could successfully install ubuntu 16.04 LTS but i'm unable to install sagemath in it. it says " unable to locate the package sagemath-upstream-binary" even when the code is correct. may i know why?

Answer (score 7):

You probably haven't added the ppa needed for it. Do

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
```

To add it and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update. Then simply typing

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

like before should do the trick.

Comment: Sagemath is in the Ubuntu universe repository - should not the repository contain all the necessary dependancies?

Comment: @CharlesGreen to quote http://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html:                 `There is also a PPA for Ubuntu available. Install SageMath this way: sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath sudo -E apt-get update sudo -E apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary`